# What's the right xpath expression to get this data?

Tags: xpath, google-docs

I'm trying to use the IMPORTXML function in Google Sheets to import data from the webpage http://chesstempo.com/chess-statistics/brainwolf.

The relevant section of code loooks like this:

```
<h3>Stats for blitz tactics</h3>
Rating: 2420.5 (RD: 291.15) (Best Active Rating: 2462 Worst Active Rating: 2221)
<br>
```

What's the right xpath expression to extract the data?

Answer (score 1):

Get the `h3` tag by text and then get the first following text sibling:

```
//h3[. = "Stats for blitz tactics"]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Demo (using google chrome console):

```
$x('//h3[. = "Stats for blitz tactics"]/following-sibling::text()[1]')
[
"Rating: 2420.5 (RD: 291.15) (Best Active Rating: 2462 Worst Active Rating: 2221)"
]
```

Comment: Putting that in the context of a google sheets function I thought it would be =ImportXML(http://chesstempo.com/chess-statistics/brainwolf,"//h3[. = "Stats for blitz tactics"]/following-sibling::text()[1]"). However, google sheets returns #ERROR!. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user1205901 watch the quotes: `ImportXML(chesstempo.com/chess-statistics/brainwolf,"//h3[. = 'Stats for blitz tactics']/following-sibling::text()[1]")`

Comment: I tried copy-pasting the version you just posted and got the error #NAME?. I then tried a slightly modified version `=ImportXML(chesstempo.com/chess-statistics/brainwolf,"//h3[. = 'Stats for blitz tactics']/following-sibling::text()[1]")` and got the error #N/A.

Comment: @user1205901 I'm not familiar with the google sheets, but may be put the url into quotes? `=ImportXML("chesstempo.com/chess-statistics/brainwolf", "//h3[. = 'Stats for blitz tactics']/following-sibling::text()[1]")`?

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. Stackoverflow is deleting the "http" from the start of chesstempo but inserting that does not make it work - it still says #N/A.

Comment: @user1205901 okay, does replacing `.` with `text()` in the xpath expression help?

Comment: When I did that the result remained #N/A.